# detect key that has been press on mouse click in Angular 2

Tags: angular, onclick, keypress, keyup

I have a angular 2 component with a div bind to a click event:

```
<div #myDiv class="myClass"
    (click)="addAnnotation($event)">
</div>
```

on click I would like to run the code addAnnotation only if the key 'a' is pressed:

```
addAnnotation(event) {
    if (the key 'a' is pressed) {
        code to run
    }
}
```

Do you know how to accomplish this?

UPDATE

I know there are keyboard events available on inputs but here I am asking if it is possible to detect which key is pressed when a mouse click occurs. The reason is that I would like to attach a dynamically created element in the point clicked only if the key 'a' is pressed.

Comment: you can detect directly on input not on div

Comment: Sorry Sajeethraran but you lost me. Could you please articulate a bit more? Basically when I click on a point within my DIV I want to attach a dynamically created element but only if the key 'a' is pressed.

Comment: @Sajeetharan means you cannot detect it on div as `click` is a mouse event and fired on left mouse click. While u want `a`, a is a key on keyboard and it is called a `KeyBoard` event. Keyboard events are only available on elements where u can focus eg: input

Comment: Mouse and key events are not usually combined. Seems like unusual request

Comment: I know that mouse and key events are not usually combined. Please see my update to understand what I am trying to achieve. I am opened to alternative ideas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an [example stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-q3lnfh)

1/ you have to make your component focusable

```
  @HostBinding('attr.tabIndex') tabIndex = -1;
```

and for prevent outline to ruin your ui you can add the css

```
 :host { outline: none !important }
```

2/ then you can listen to keypress event to stock the current active key, and keyup to flush it.

3/ Then on click, you check the active key to see if the 'a' is pressed and run your code.

Answer (score 0):

You're after the `keydown`/`keyup` events, not a `click` event.

These events though, are only available through focusable elements, like an `<input />`.

In general, I'd `console.log` the `$event` argument being sent to you to see what I have in my possession.

Comment: When I click on a point within my DIV I want to attach a dynamically created element on that point but only if the key 'a' is pressed.